# How to give general maximum to a html-site completely based on css with vw-units?

Tags: html, css

I built a site where nearly every element got it's size in vw-units. So text, padding, margin, height and width of every element is set in "vw". This works great.

My problem is that there should be a change and now the site should not scale over 1200px-width any more. That means if the screen is wider than 1200px the site should not fill 100% of the width and every element should be as big as it would be on 1200px screen width.

For sure I have a div with a max-width of 1200px but everything inside is still growing with the screen.

I know that I can use 1200px as a breakpoint and that I can define every element again beyond that. But that is what I want to avoid.

My question means: Is there any way to modify the css-unit "vw" in the way that it uses 1200px as base-width for every wider screen than that?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: I have made a minimal example here: http://jsfiddle.net/z4gcqg3b/ Change the scrren width... Everything except the container is in vw-units. I want to stop the rescaling of all inner elements for bigger screens without touching every single element.

Answer (score 0):

If you're uing a container element, you can set it's `max-width`, which will not allow the width of the element to exceed the amount you specified.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #faa;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
    background-color: #afa;
    width: 60vw;
    max-width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
#container p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <p>This div's width can't go any further than 200 pixels.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but this does not change anything in the case that I have to define this for every element and these are a lot. On the other hand there are a lot of paddings, margins and font-sizes which do not have a max-width specification or something similiar or do I miss somethintg here?

Answer (score 0):

I found your question after having solved the same exact problem, and then wondering if there was a different solution. It seems like it’s a common issue right?

Unfortunately, my solution probably won’t work for any one since I have a very dynamic site where almost all my CSS dimensions get put through a function at runtime. Therefore it  is able to modify it for exactly this situation. It works for what I’m doing but I can hardly recommended as a good practice.

The only other solution I could think of is to multiply everything by a sort of fake VW unit.

```
.dog-image
{
    // 50vw
    width: calc(50 * min(1vw, 12px));
}
```

So when the screen is wider than 1200px then it is limited to 50 * 12px.

I haven’t actually tested this so I don’t know if there are any rounding errors. An alternative approach should fix that.

```
width: min(50vw, calc(50 * 12px));
```

If you’re using a css preprocessor you could probably make a function to do this for you.